# вывода на экран всех трехзначных чисел

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста. Задача составить программу вывода на экран всех трехзначных чисел, кратных 9. Как сделать вывод в текст. файл?

```
uses crt;
var i: integer;
begin
for i:=100 to 999 do
    if i mod 9=0 then write(i,' ');
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uses crt;

var 
  i: integer;
  txtFile: TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(txtFile, "output.txt");
  Rewrite(txtFile);
  try
    i := 108;
    while i < 1000 do
    begin
      Write(txtFile, i, ' ');
      i := i + 9;
    end;
  finally
    CloseFile(txtFile);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Необходимо уточнить, какой паскаль у пользователя. AssignFile и CloseFile - это уже freepascal. Если у пользователя старый паскаль, необходимо использовать Assign и Close. В старом паскале также нет конструкций try... finally...